# How to set the visible area of a sf::Text

Tags: sfml

I am making some classes to help create a GUI using *SFML*. I would like to be able to display only a part of a `sf::Text`. Something like `setTextureRect` in the `sf::Sprite` class.

The only solution I found was to draw the text to a `sf::RenderTexture` and then I assign its texture to a sprite. I can then draw this sprite on the window.

```
//The class contains :
sf::RenderTexture buffer;

//When the class is created :
buffer.create(window.getSize().x,window.getSize().y);

//To draw on the screen :
window.clear();
buffer.clear();

buffer.draw(text);
buffer.display();

sprite.setTexture(buffer.getTexture());

window.draw(sprite);
window.display();
```

This allows me to use `sf::Sprite::setTextureRect`, but it is very slow. I measured that it is about 100 times slower than a direct draw. I tried creating the buffer to the size of the text but it had almost no impact on the performance.

So my question is, is there a way to display only a part of a sf::Text (or sf::Shape) that would be more efficient?

Comment: If you are trying to show only a specific set of the letters then it would be easier to just cut the word before sending it to the text, are you trying to do that or do you want to include partial letters as well?

Comment: I would like to include partial letters to be able to make scrollbars for example. The text is sometimes partially visible like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/csKgl.png

Comment: In the example you showed, this could be solved by just drawing the outer box first so that it covers up the text as it scrolls down, then not continuing to draw the text that is outside the box, does that mean that the text you have needs to be larger than the outside box or is your situation a little different?

Comment: I don't really want the position of the elements to be limited by the police size used.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I think I have an idea that might work, just to make sure, is this just for a list that would scroll like in the example picture?

Answer (score 4):

You can use sf::View to determine what is drawn and what not.
Remember that the rectangle that is drawn, with respect to the window, use the range 0.f - 1.f.

The [tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-view.php) can help.

Comment: I don't think this works all the time. For example : http://i.imgur.com/FsvnP.png if the name of a person is too long and you want to cut it before the age collumn, then you can't at the same time display a part of the list movable via a scrollbar. Because I don't think it's possible to have a view's viewport displayed via another view.

Comment: @Heckel In such cases it begins to complicate, but I do not think it's impossible. You can use a view for each column.

Comment: @Heckel Its possible if you now the area of the sf::Text which should get displayed and the visible area of the scrollbar. Instead of trying to combine the two views, you can calculate the overlaping area of both and create a sf.:View with this data. But it get really complicated when the default view of the window have to be respected.

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, there's no method to do this in sf::Text.
http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1-fr/classsf_1_1Text.php

However, if as you said, you want to do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxuBs.png

You can compute the size of the sf::Text and cut it before it exceeds the size of the frame (and eventually replace the last characters).
For example, "Person 2554548747848874874" will be "Person 25545..".
It's smooth and a lot of list are done this way. (You have an example with the Windows task explorer)

As DarkPhantom said, there's also sf::View, but you'll have to try to see if it's reliable to do a lot of setView().

Comment: This doesn't really help for text that scrolls smoothly off the bottom of the screen

Comment: To do this, he just needs to draw the grey interface after the text.

Comment: Unless he wants this to act as an interface in a larger window, i.e. a windowed menu inside a game.

Comment: Then it'll be: 1) draw the game 2) draw the list 3) draw the interface. It just requires a little marge under the interface to avoid the list from exceeding outside of the interface.http://imgur.com/586GyZg

Comment: If he has large text and small borders it still wouldn't work.

Comment: The last way would be to have every letters of his text into a .png. And to use vertex array to place each letters individually  and eventually to cut them by modifying the vertex.texCoords. It's faster than following his method, but it's the same idea.

Comment: That's awfully inefficient, it would be easier to just split the background image into pieces around the window and render those or as DarkPhantom suggested use a sf:View inside the scrolling menu.

Comment: If sf::View is efficient, it is a good way to do what he wants, yes.

Comment: I do not think changing the view cause a noticeable difference in performance: [source](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp#L405)